# Bypassing method()/function() code upon ACL check failure. Without using IF statement, or return;

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I'm using Kohana 3.2 with Controller_Template. Basically what I would like to do is to check the ACL of each action_method. If fail, load the access denied view and skip the rest of the action_method code; else continue loading.

I know I could use an if...else statement to do a simple boolean check (or even do a `if(check_permission())return;`), but I hope there is a more elegant way of handling it with the least amount of extraneous code in the `action_page()`... if possible, just `check_permission();`. I'm okay with adding more code within `function check_permission()`

```
function check_permission() {
    $this->template->content = View::factory('system/access_denied')
        ->bind('title', $title);
    $title = 'Access Denied';
}

function action_page() {
    check_permission();

    $this->template->content = View::factory('page/index')
        ->bind('title', $title);
        ->bind('data', $data);

    $title = 'Page loaded';
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Perhaps there is some way specifically in kohana that can achieve this? Native php is fine too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a nice ACL module you can take the [Acl of the Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/de/zend.acl.html). [Here](https://github.com/kolanos/kohana-zend) is the Kohana module that include the Zend Framework.

You can use it like this:

start:

```
$acl = new Zend_Acl();
```

add roles:

```
$acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('guest'))
  ->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('member'))
  ->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('admin'));
```

add resources (controller):

```
$acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('someController'));
```

allow access for role and privileges (action) of a resouce (controller):

```
 $acl->allow('member', 'someController' array('page'));
```

then check in you befor method the permission of the user:

```
public function befor() 
{
    $role = .... // role from user
    $resource = $this->request->controller();
    $action = $this->request->action();

    if ($acl->isAllowed($role, $resource, $action)) 
    {
      //...redirect
    }
}
```

Is this, what you looking for?

Comment: Actually, I'm already using Wouter's ACL module which is very similar to Zend. My `if(!$this->enforce_privilege('page','delete')) return;` contains the `$acl->isAllowed()` with some code to load access denied view. +1 for effort anyway


Until I find a better solution I'm using
`if(!$this->check_permission('page','view')) return;`

Answer (score 0):

I think [`Request::current()->redirect('...')`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Request#redirect) an [`befor()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Controller_Template#before) will to help you.

like this:

```
  public function befor() 
  {
    parent::befor();

    if (... have no access) 
    {
       Request::current()->redirect('access/denied');
    }
  }
```

...

```
Class Access extends Controller_Template {

  public function action_denied() 
  {
    $this->template->content = View::factory('system/access_denied')
        ->bind('title', $title);
    $title = 'Access Denied';
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, the problem that I face with that is I'm unable to check the permission for individual controller methods (within the method); unless I create a lookup array of the available methods and map them to their privileges in `before()`. However that is not what I'm looking for :(